# Tube and CapForm

Tags: graphics, bugs, rendering

**EDIT**

Bug still present in version 13.0 when number of coordinates is large. See answer below by kglr.

**Original Post**

I am using version 10  to draw tubes. With the CapForm set as Butt the first pipe is as expected but the bent pipe has one rounded end. Is this a bug? How can I fix this? Thanks

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm["Butt"], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1000, 0, 0}}, 30], 
Tube[{{0, 300, 0}, {1000, 300, 0}, {1000, 300, 100}}, 30]}, 
 Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Looks like a bug, it's not there in V9. I suggest you contact support.

Comment: I get a rounded end on a straight, segmented tube, too: `Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {800, 0, 0}, {1000, 0, 0}}, 30]`

Comment: In version 8 the ends are flat in both examples, too. So definitely a bug.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it is/was in 10.0.0 (also last beta).

Comment: gets worse: try `Tube[Reverse@{{0, 300, 0}, {1000, 300, 0}, {1000, 300, 100}}, 30]`.

Comment: @kguler Yes it does get worse -both ends rounded and the bend broken. I have not yet had a reply from Wolfram.

Comment: Hugh, have received a response from WRI re this bug yet? Looks like it is still there in v12.

Comment: @kglr I have checked my email and have not had a response to say the bug is fixed. It is CASE:1665254. Shame it is back.

Comment: Hugh, maybe we should remove  "fixed in version .."?

Comment: @kglr I have tried my original problem in V12. It worked correctly. I was also able to check it in V11.2 where it worked correctly. I can't check older versions. Are we sure this is the problem?

Comment: Hugh, there is no problem with the example in your question. But with more points in the first  argument of `Tube` the issue comes back. Try for example `coords1` or `coords2` in my answer.

Comment: @kglr Just tried it. Yes you are correct. The problem returns. Shall I reset the bug statement? Not done this before do we record this elsewhere?

Comment: I think just removing the first line in the post would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed in 10.0.2 . On windows 7, 64 bits

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm["Butt"], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1000, 0, 0}}, 30], 
 Tube[{{0, 300, 0}, {1000, 300, 0}, {1000, 300, 100}}, 30]}, 
 Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is still there as of version 13.

For example, adding more points in the example in OP:

```
coords1 = Table[{i, 0, 0}, {i, 0, 1000, 20}];
coords2 = Join[Table[{i, 400, 0}, {i, 0, 1000, 20}], 
    Table[{1000, 400, i}, {i, 0, 200, 10}]];

$Version
```

> "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm["Butt"], Red, Tube[coords1, 100], 
  Blue, Tube[coords2, 100]},  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

A work-around (no idea why/how it works) is to add the directive `Opacity[.9999]`:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.9999], CapForm["Butt"], Red, Tube[coords1, 100], 
  Blue, Tube[coords2, 100]},  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Note:** Bumped into this issue and the mysterious work-around while answering [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202441/125).

**Update:** Much less mysterious workaround: set a *large enough* value for  the `Method` supoption `"TubePoints"`:

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm["Butt"], Red, Tube[coords1,100], Blue, Tube[coords2, 100]},  
   Boxed -> False, 
   Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 50}]
```

[image]