# Discontinuous Tube visualization

Tags: plotting

```
Clear["`.*"]
a = 2; h = 0.4 a ; z[th_] = a th/6; thmax = 10; tr = 0.1 a  ;
aa = ParametricPlot3D[{ a Cos[th], a Sin[th],  h th/( 2 Pi)}, {th, 0, 
   thmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Tube[tr]}, Axes -> False, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
lamb = Pi /2 ;
TR[t_] = tr (SquareWave[t/lamb]/2 + 1/2)
Plot[tr (SquareWave[t/lamb]/2 + 1/2), {t, 0, thmax}, 
 Exclusions -> None]
Plot[TR[t], {t, 0, thmax}]
bb = ParametricPlot3D[{ a Cos[th], a Sin[th],  h th/( 2 Pi)}, {th, 0, 
   thmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Tube[TR[th]]}, Axes -> False, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

An attempt was made to visualize Tube segments cut away at regular intervals of $\theta = (2 k-1)\pi/4$ by function definition (1-0-1-0- amplitude ) type. Expected Tube division image is sketched. Getting such an image was not successful because variable tube radii $( 0.2,0,0.2,0,..)$ as coded here does not work.

Earlier [Reap&Sow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104863/continuously-varying-tube-radius) also did not help.

Please help.

Comment: Apologies, the question did not convey properly. So I have redone the entire question with graphics. Hope it is now clearer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** You can use your function `TR` with `RegionFunction`:

```
a = 2; h = 0.4 a; thmax = 10;
ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[th], a Sin[th],  h th/(2 Pi)}, {th, 0, thmax},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Tube[.2]}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
  RegionFunction-> (TR[#4] == .2&)]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use it with `ConditionalExpression` (or  with `Piecewise`) to change the first argument of `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[ConditionalExpression[{a Cos[th], a Sin[th], h th/(2 Pi)}, TR[th]==.2], 
 {th, 0, thmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red,Tube[.2]}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

> same picture

**Original answer:**

Using `MeshFunctions` + `Mesh` + `MeshShading`:

```
n = 1000;
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[th], Sin[th], th/5}, {th, 0, thmax}, 
  PlotStyle -> Yellow, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All,
  BaseStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], JoinForm["Round"]], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
  Mesh -> {Subdivide[0, thmax, n]}, 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  MeshShading -> {Red, None}] /. Line -> (Tube[#, .18] &)
```

[image]

**Neat Examples:**

Play with combinations of  `CapForm["Butt"]`/`CapForm[None]` and `MeshShading -> {Red, None}` / `MeshShading -> Dynamic @ {RandomColor[], None}` to get nice effects like:

[image]

With `n = 500`, change the replacement rule to

```
 Line -> (Dynamic[Tube[#, RandomReal[{.05, .3}]]] &)
```

to make the tube radii random to get effects like:

[image]

**Note:** MichaelE2 brought to my attention that in version 12 the code above produces tube segments with rounded caps [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/564Gd.png).

Changing `MeshShading` to

```
 MeshShading -> {Opacity[.99999, Red], None}
```

or changing the post-processing rule to

```
 {Line -> (Tube[#, .18]& ), r_RGBColor :> Opacity[.999, r] }
```

or to

```
 Line-> (Tube[#, .18] & /@ Partition[#, 2, 1]& )
```

fixes this issue (don't know why/how though). Perhaps, the issue reported in [this q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60640/125) that is supposed to be fixed in v10.2 lingers.

Yet another fix is to add the option

```
Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 50}
```

to `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: It does not work for me :( -- http://i.stack.imgur.com/YklQ7.png It's more obvious with fewer sections: http://i.stack.imgur.com/564Gd.png Close-up: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqc3N.png (Version 12.0, Mac)

Comment: @MichaelE2, it works in v9./windows10. In v12 (Wolfram Cloud) i got similar issues, but when i copy paste the output into a v9 desktop notebook it renders fine, so i thought the issue is related to browser version. Changing the replacement rule to `Line-> (Tube[#, .18]&/@Partition[#,2,1]& )` seems to fix it on the browser version; can you check if it works in v12 desktop?

Comment: Yes, the cylindrical disks are properly separated.  However, there is a yellow line threading through them: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jhdQS.png - Is that supposed to be there? I thought it would have been the `Line` that was replaced.

Comment: @MichaelE2, those are mesh points styled wrong; `MeshStyle -> Opacity[0]` fixes it.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, it works with Region function and my ( boolean a sort of TR indirectly) defined function for TR. Also could you please explain how $#4$ is in the $TR[#4] $ is chosen ?

Comment: @Narasimham, in a single parameter `ParametricPlot3D` (as in `ParametricPlot[{x[t],y[t],z[t]}, {t, a, b}]`, `RegionFunction` arguments are `x`,`y`,`z` and `t` in that order, that is a region function is a function with up to 4 arguments; `#4` stands for the fourth argument (which is `th` in your case). An alternative way to specify the same region function  is `RegionFunction -> Function[{x,y,z,t},TR[t]]`.

Comment: That simple ! thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It works for me if you add more [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html)and let [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)wild

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {Cos[th], Sin[th], th/5}
 , {th, 0, thmax}
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Tube[TR[th]]}
 , Axes -> False
 , Boxed -> False
 , PlotRange -> All
 , PlotPoints -> 5000
 , MaxRecursion -> Infinity
 ]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But there should be regularly many segments of complete disconnection.

Comment: @Narasimham can you be more specific about the problem? I do see *"regularly many segments of complete disconnect. "*, as you ask. There are just very thinly sliced. See edit.